# Are orthogonal projection and conjugation exchangeable?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

Given ${\bf x} \in \Bbb C^n$, and let $S$ be a subspace of $\Bbb C^n$, the question is if projection of ${\bf x}$ and the conjugation of ${\bf x}$ are exchangeable, i.e.

> Is ${\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_S}{\mathbf{\bar x}} = \overline {{\text{pro}}{{\text{j}}_S}{\mathbf{x}}} $ ?

We can assume standard inner product, then the above is clearly true if we project ${\bf x} = (x_1 ,...,x_n)$ to the span of some standard basis vectors, say $(x_1 ,...,x_n) \to (x_1,x_2,0,...,0)$.

Please help give a proof or a counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: To make a projection we need the vector space to be endowed with a inner product.

Comment: @Maffred Thanks. Let's assume the standard inner product.

Comment: @Maffred: only if you want your projection tombe orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the space be $\mathbb C^2$ with the standard inner product and the element $z=(1,i)$ and the space to be $Y -iX=0$. This should be a counterexample.